# Inverse probability weighting (IPW) with positive and negative treatments?

Tags: propensity-scores, weighted-regression

I am studying the effects of the government intervention which can take two directions and is usually represented as follows:

> $Treat = \left\{\begin{matrix}
>  & +1 (intervene), if state A\\ 
>  &0 (do nothing), if all  is  ok \\ 
>  & -1 (intervene  in opposite direction) if B
> \end{matrix}\right.$

Is it possible to do in the IPW setting? The key is that A and B (1 and -1) are the opposite. They are not really ordered and representing them as 0, 1, 2 would not make sense. Treatment is actually a censored variable so most of the time it is zero and then when the combination of covariates is above a certain treshold it is +1, when it is below it is -1.

I would appreaciate if somebody can help. I run straight to the stata but I saw that probit does not allow for negative treatment values and that in the case of multiple treatments only logit is used (why?). Am I missing something theoretically or should I just use R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually in a standard multi-category treatment scenario. The fact that treatment -1 is in the opposite direction as treatment 1 is a matter of the interpretation of the causal effect you estimate, not a matter of how the effects are estimated. So any literature you read on multi-category (nominal) treatments will apply here. Mccaffrey et al (2013; doi:10.1002/sim.5753) is a great resource.

Essentially, you estimate a multinomial logit/probit model and compute the predicted probability of each treatment for each individual (so each individual will have three predicted probabilities). You need to ensure the treatment is modeled as a categorical variable. The IPW is the inverse of the probability of being in the treatment actually received. Then you can estimate a weighted regression or ANOVA to estimate the causal contrasts of interest (e.g., +1 vs 0, -1 vs. 0, +1 vs -1).

If you decide not to use Stata, the `WeightIt` package in R is well equipped to estimate IPWs for multi-category treatments.

Comment: Thanks. I actually came here from the propensity score matching literature and a was a bit confused, because I was still thinking that -1/1 somehow need to be matched to 0. (actually, probability estimate for either -1/1 is always close to zero, which makes sense)

Comment: I did use R. Could you maybe help me, in this setting, how do I estimate the causal effect? Just do weighted regression of the outcome of treatment, with weights from ipw? (i.e., lm(outcome ~ treatment, weights = ipw.weights ) )

Comment: Yes, exactly, although you need robust standard errors. Use `jtools::summ(lm(...), robust = TRUE, confint = TRUE)`. Make sure your treatment variable is a factor.

Comment: The fact that Stata requires your treatment to have non-negative values is just a feature of stata, right?

Comment: Yes. Remember that the coding of a variable is arbitrary. Just because you interpret treatment "-1" as negative, that doesn't have any bearing on how a statistical program or analysis should consider it. You could recode your treatments as 0, 1, 2 or 1, 2, 3 and reach an identical conclusion. It's solely a matter of the interpretation of the causal effect that "-1" is "opposite" "1", but that has nothing to do with how the variable is coded or entered into a software.